# Flutter web | shouldn't I build website in terms of SEO?

Tags: flutter-web

I would like to create website and wondering if there is something I can do for SEO.
I hope my website would hit when someone searched.
Should I go with HTML?

Comment: Any solution for SEO with flutter web ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not too good. You can add SEO META tags but they will be the same for the whole single page app because Flutter Web's navigation is based on hashes - bad for crawlers trying to index your site. Flutter people from Google say that Flutter Web is more for SPA (single page web apps) - not meant for sites that have a lot of content that requires good SEO optimisation. So you can do some SEO but not much really. It's semi ok to have a website with content and the app separately but ideally, you would like to have a good SEO for your whole app. So Flutter Web in terms of SEO is (at least at the moment) a "cheap solution" and ideally you should have a web app not Flutter.

Google also recently announced that their crawler renders JS now but Google isn't the only search engine so ideally, you want all of the search engines to be able to read your site.

Comment: As of today, UI elements (texts and  images) gets drawn on canvas therefore can't be crawled from DOM. This is a hot topic in Flutter community and I guess there will be some solutions in the future since SEO is crucial for web. These issues are still active: [SEO](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46789), [SSR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47600).