# How good are Flutter web apps from an SEO point of view?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How good are Flutter web apps from an SEO point of view since Flutter uses HTML5 Canvas heavily and supports Single Page Web Apps only? Are there ways to still get good SEO for flutter apps given this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter web | shouldn't I build website in terms of SEO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60752625/flutter-web-shouldnt-i-build-website-in-terms-of-seo)